# validating the range of dates

Tags: jquery

i'm using  a datepicker to pick a date for my form, how can i control that the date can't be greater than the actual day, and how can i control that another date should be between -x days and +x days?

thanks.

i try, the next code, but it doesn't work.

```
$.validator.addMethod("greaterThan",
                function(value, element, params) {
                    if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
                        return new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val());
                    }
                    return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val())
                        || (parseFloat(value) > parseFloat($(params).val()));
                    }, 'Must be greater than {0}.');


$.datepicker.setDefaults({

    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sa'],
    monthNames: ['Enero de', 'Febrero de', 'Marzo de', 'Abril de', 'Mayo de', 'Junio de', 'Julio de', 'Agosto de', 'Septiembre de', 'Octubre de', 'Noviembre de', 'Diciembre de'],
    nextText: 'Siguiente',
    prevText: 'Anterior'

});

$(function() {
    $("#tbFechaInicio").datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
});
$(function() {
    $("#tbFechaEntrega").datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the jQuery UI date picker component?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max

You can use the `minDate` and `maxDate` options to specify limits, even using + and - to have a dynamic date range available. This can also limit the input into the textbox to a valid date.

It's a great tool, and why reinvent the wheel!

Comment: mm never think about that, thanks,i´m just searching here, i'm gonna look at that right now

Comment: i try it like the jquery ui page, but doesn't work, its just like their example

Comment: @AlejandroHinestrosa The example on the jQuery UI page doesn't work? Very odd as it works fine for me in all browsers. Looks like the answer by Justin Nafe is the jQuery UI datepicker options and they're working for you, so you're set?

Comment: That is rare - do you have a standard install of Firefox? Or have you changed any settings? Again, the Jquery UI demo is working fine in Firefox 10.0.2 for me. Have you tried a "hard" refresh (CTRL + F5)?

Comment: that was just to rare, after a lots of builds a rebuilds, finally did it, it works, i don't know why the bug, but finally is working thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can control the max date and the min date with something like the following

```
$("#yourdatepickerid").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    maxDate: '-1d',
    minDate: new Date(2008, 1 - 1, 1)
});
```